# Cumulative days across rows with several constraints SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to figure out how to return a single line per Asset which shows the total days of cumulative Periods. However, I only want to add certain Periods depending on whether the StartDate is within 10 days of the EndDate of the previous Period.

TotalDays column in the sample data: If a Period does not have an EndDate the total days is Today (13/10/2018) minus the StartDate.

Breakdown of the Expected Output Table:

- Row 1 / Asset1: TotalDays is 278 because

  - Period 2 started 1 day after Period 1 ended
  - and Period 3 started 6 days after Period 2 ended
  - therefore 63+29+186 = 278
- Row 2 / Asset 2: TotalDays is 120 because

  - Period 1 and 2 are both Open so use the earliest StartDate
  - Today minus 15/06/2018 = 120
- Row 3 / Asset 3: TotalDays is 66 because

  - Period 2 started over 10 days after Period 1 ended

If an Asset has no Open Periods it would not be displayed in the Output.

Happy to clarify anything as I know this is a bit fiddly!

Many Thanks.

Data Sample:

```
+-----+---------+--------+------------+------------+-----------+--------------------------------------+--------+
| Row | AssetID | Period | StartDate  |  EndDate   | TotalDays | DaysBetweenEndDateAndStartDateOfNext | Status |
+-----+---------+--------+------------+------------+-----------+--------------------------------------+--------+
|   1 |       1 |      1 | 01/01/2018 | 05/03/2018 |        63 | NULL                                 | Closed |
|   2 |       1 |      2 | 06/03/2018 | 04/04/2018 |        29 | 1                                    | Closed |
|   3 |       1 |      3 | 10/04/2018 | NULL       |       186 | 6                                    | Open   |
|   4 |       2 |      1 | 15/06/2018 | NULL       |       120 | NULL                                 | Open   |
|   5 |       2 |      2 | 01/07/2018 | NULL       |       104 | NULL                                 | Open   |
|   6 |       3 |      1 | 01/02/2018 | 10/02/2018 |         9 | NULL                                 | Closed |
|   7 |       3 |      2 | 08/08/2018 | NULL       |        66 | 179                                  | Open   |
+-----+---------+--------+------------+------------+-----------+--------------------------------------+--------+
```

Expected Output:

```
+-----+---------+------------+---------+-----------+
| Row | AssetID | StartDate  | EndDate | TotalDays |
+-----+---------+------------+---------+-----------+
|   1 |       1 | 01/01/2018 | NULL    |       278 |
|   2 |       2 | 15/06/2018 | NULL    |       120 |
|   3 |       3 | 08/08/2018 | NULL    |        66 |
+-----+---------+------------+---------+-----------+
```

Comment: Do you actually have the `DaysBetweenEndDateAndStartDateOfNext` column in your table?

Comment: Hi Salman, yes it is a column in the table.